# Why less, uglify and watch wont work in real time?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, less, watch

I have tried many ways to make this work automatically, but it wont. It loads changes to less and js files when I start console with grunt command but than nothing happens untill I restart? Does anyone knows where do I make mistake?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {scope: 'devDependencies'});

  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    watch: {
      less: {
        files: ['style/less/**/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less:development'],
        options: {
        livereload: true,
        }
      },
      uglify: {
        files: ['src/*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify:my_target'],
        options: {
        livereload: 1337,
        },
      }
    },

    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2,
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapRootpath: '/',
          sourceMapBasepath: 'app'
        },
        files: {
          'styles/css/style.min.css': 'styles/less/style.less',
        }
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'JS/custom.min.js': ['JS/custom.js']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'less:development', 'uglify:my_target',
    'watch'
  ]);

};
```

Comment: Use livereload only on your uglified/less'd files and try changing the src for your uglify:my_target and less tasks to the same relative src as in the watch task: style/less/**/*.less' etc.. See this link https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#live-reload-with-preprocessors

Comment: Do I need two livereloads for less and uglify or I just need to put destination folders?                                                                               watch: {
      less: {
        files: ['styles/less/**/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less:development']
      },
      uglify: {
        files: ['src/*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify:my_target']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: { livereload: true },
        files: ['styles/JS/**/*']
      }
    },

Comment: Just one livereload to monitor both uglify and less outputs.=> files: ['lessOutputLocation','uglifyOutputLocation']

Comment: Ok, I made some progress, console is showing that I've changed less or js file, but it still doesn't write it in minified file? It said: File "JS\custom.js" changed.
Completed in 0.001s at Thu Feb 16 2017 12:57:40 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time) - Waiting... This is how it looks now: livereload: {
        options: { livereload: true },
        files: ['styles/**/*.less', 'JS/**/*.js']
      }